# JavaScript Map Reduce Function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and using JSON datasource trying to aggregate data to display correctly on webpage, and this dataset gets subsetted based on user activity.  Some of these datasets can get to be 100s of records, so being fast is important.

```js
//Here is my data
{
"metadata": {
    "mm": {
        "filter": false
    }
},
"categories": [{
        "data": [

        ],
        "name": "category_one"
    },

    {
        "data": [{
                "name": "13_WH1",
                "attributes": {
                    "bv": 145
                },
                "vm": [
                    4.0,
                    8.0,
                    6.0,
                    6.0
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "32_WH2",
                "attributes": {
                    "bv": 155
                },
                "vm": [
                    5.0,
                    7.0,
                    7.0,
                    2.0
                ]
            }
        ],
        "name": "category_two"
    }
]
}

function sumVm(data_set) {
  data_set.map(function(series, index) {
    const total_vm = series.data.reduce(
      (accumulator, record) => accumulator + record.vm,
      0
    );
    console.log(total_vm)
    return total_vm

  })
};
```

When I call the function, here is my result (which is just repeating each record, not adding by position.

```
sumVm(jsonData)
# 04,8,6,65,7,7,2
```

The desired result i would want is:

```
# 9,15,13,8
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. `record.vm` appears to be an array, so it's not clear what you expect the addition operator to do. It's not clear what you expect out of this because of all of the errors and inconsistencies. Please clean this up.

Comment: @JaredSmith - thank you i now cleaned up the json so valid.

Comment: @Spectric - i'm certainly open to easier ways of doing this, if you have suggestions on cleaner and understable, please share.  thank you

Comment: Hello, does my answer answer your question? I noticed you haven't accepted any answer, yet you haven't made any comments regarding what they were missing. Just curious.

Comment: @jKraut I've voted to reopen your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it. Flat mapping and then using foreach to build a new array of values.

```js
let jsonData = [{
  "foo": "bar",
  "data": [{
      "name": "13_WH1",
      "attributes": {
        "bv": 145,
      },
      "vm": [
        4.0,
        8.0,
        6.0,
        6.0
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "32_WH2",
      "attributes": {
        "bv": 155,
      },
      "vm": [
        5.0,
        7.0,
        7.0,
        2.0
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

function sumVm(data_set) {
  let a = []
  let d = data_set.flatMap(e => e.data.map(d => d.vm));
  d.forEach(e => e.forEach((f, i) => {
    if (!a[i]) a[i] = 0;
    a[i] = a[i] + f
  }))
  return a
};

console.log(sumVm(jsonData))
// 9,15,13,8
```

Comment: @Kinglist, thx for answering, but i get this when i run in my App ```react-dom.production.min.js:125 TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined```

Comment: I updated my answer. See if that validates OK

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the first item's `vm` property and use a nested loop to loop through all items and extract the `vm` property, then get the item at the index and add to a variable. Push this value to an array:

```js
var res = [];
jsonData.data[0].vm.forEach((e, i) => {
  let sum = 0;
  jsonData.data.forEach(f => sum += f.vm[i]), res.push(sum)
})
```

Demo:

```js
const jsonData={data:[{name:"13_WH1",attributes:{bv:145},vm:[4,8,6,6]},{name:"32_WH2",attributes:{bv:155},vm:[5,7,7,2]}]};

var res = [];
jsonData.data[0].vm.forEach((e, i) => {let sum = 0; jsonData.data.forEach(f => sum += f.vm[i]), res.push(sum)})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here may this help to solve your problem:

```js
const jsonData ={
  "data": [{
    "name": "13_WH1",
    "attributes": {
      "bv": 145
    },
    "vm": [
      4.0,
      8.0,
      6.0,
      6.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "32_WH2",
    "attributes": {
      "bv": 155
    },
    "vm": [
      5.0,
      7.0,
      7.0,
      2.0
    ]
  }]
};

//Using curly brackets function
function sumVm(data_set) {
  return data_set.data
  .map(function(element){
    return element.vm
  })
  .reduce(function(total_vm, current_vm){
    return total_vm.map(function(element, index){
      return element + current_vm[index];
    });
  });
};

//Using arrow function
function sumVm_arrowFunction(data_set) {
  return data_set.data
  .map(element =>  element.vm)
  .reduce((total_vm, current_vm) =>
    total_vm.map((element, index) => element + current_vm[index])
  );
};

//One-liner using arrow function
function sumVm_OneLiner(data_set) {
  return data_set.data.map(element =>  element.vm).reduce((total_vm, current_vm) => total_vm.map((element, index) => element + current_vm[index]));
};

//Ultra one-liner arrow function
const sumVm_ultOneLine = (data_set) => data_set.data.map(element =>  element.vm).reduce((total_vm, current_vm) => total_vm.map((element, index) => element + current_vm[index]));


// The all functions above work same and return the same results
// It's only about different ways to write the callback functions
// You may choose any form of function that fits to your preferences & requirements

console.log(sumVm(jsonData))
console.log(sumVm_arrowFunction(jsonData))
console.log(sumVm_OneLiner(jsonData))
console.log(sumVm_ultOneLine(jsonData))
```

The algorithm:

- Get the value of "data" (jsonData.data)
- The loop through it using map and make it returns the value of "vm" array (jsonData.data.vm)
- Then reduce it by mapping each element inside the "vm" array and aggregate it to next corresponding "vm"

Hope this answers your problem